# Passing an image with intent causes "Failed Binder Transaction", but still displays image correctly

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

**FIXED

In the end I created my bitmap on the last activity instead of passing it with intents which solved the problem.**

So I'm taking an image and some text and then place it on the image, then I scale the bitmap and create a new bitmap from that. Then pass that bitmap with an intent to the next activity which shows the image and gives an option to save that image to sd.

Although I do get the failed binder transaction which seemed to be caused by passing too much data between intents, but the image still gets passed fine so should I worry about the error or ignore it because it still works like it should?

I create/shrink the bitmap like this

```
    strTop = txtTop.getText().toString();
    strButtom = txtButtom.getText().toString();
    combinedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), lstImages.get(index)).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
    paint.setColor(Color.RED); 
    paint.setTextSize(combinedBitmap.getHeight()/10); 
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(combinedBitmap);
    canvas.drawText(strTop, (canvas.getWidth() / 2), paint.getTextSize()+10, paint);
    canvas.drawText(strButtom, (canvas.getWidth() / 2), combinedBitmap.getHeight()-paint.getTextSize()-10, paint);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SaveToSD.class);
    int width = combinedBitmap.getWidth();
    int height = combinedBitmap.getHeight();
    int newWidth = 400;
    int newHeight = 240;
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    Bitmap newbm = Bitmap.createBitmap(combinedBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix,true);
    intent.putExtra("combinedBitmap", newbm);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And I retrieve it with this code:
`combinedBitmap = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("combinedBitmap");
            imgView.setImageBitmap(combinedBitmap);`